# Product Rule for 2nd Order Tensors

Tags: calculus, tensors

Lets take three second order tensors $ A $, $ B $ and $ C $ . What is the derivative of $ABC$ w.r.t to a vector $x$. To me it seems like the general derivative rule does not follow here.

Edit 1:

$ A $ is defined as
$ A = A_{ij} e_i⊗e_j $.
$ B $ is defined as
$ B = B_{kl} e_k⊗e_l $.
$ C $ is defined as
$ C = C_{mn} e_m⊗e_n $

Let $ D $ be a second order tensor such that
$ D = A_{ij}B_{jm}C_{mn} e_i⊗e_n $
Find $dD/dx$ in terms of $A$, $B$ and $C$.

Comment: Are you talking about the covariant derivative of the tensor product of three second order tensor fields?

Comment: Yes!!. What I am sure of is that it will give third order tensor, though I am not sure of the exact formula.

Comment: If $A,B$ and $C$ haver order $2$ then the product will have order $6$. The covariant derivative increases the order but evaluating at $x$ decreases it again, so overall $\nabla_x(ABC)$ will have order $6$. Then I think this is not what you mean.

Comment: Composition of three 2nd order tensor, should yield a 2nd order tensor. And then a  derivative of a 2nd order tensor with a vector should yield a 3rd order tensor. My mistake the above is composition of three 2nd order tensors.

Comment: So I guess $A$, $B$ and $C$ are $(1,1)$-tensor fields?

Comment: Sorry I could not understand the above statement. I have updated the question.

Comment: Ok that looks better! Now what do you mean by $dD/dx$? is $x$ the parameter of some curve in the space $A,B,C$ and $D$ live in? or is it a tangent vector? For example what is $de_i/dx$?

Comment: $e_i$ are orthonormal basis, therefore $ de_i/dx = 0 (2nd order tensor) $. And $ A $,$ B $and$ C $are tensor valued vector function of $x$ for ex $A(x)$, $B(x)$ and  $C(x)$. For example $x$ could be a vector say $ (x_1,x_2,x_3) $ and $ A $ could be $[(x_1,x_2,x_3);(2x_1,2x_2,2x_3);(3x_1,3x_2,3x_3)]e_i⊗e_j$